# Citing only e-books in Bachelor thesis

Tags: citations, thesis, books

I want to know, are e-books (digital version) comparable to physical books in citations? Can I use only e-books instead of real books for finding citations, notes to put in my Bachelor thesis?

Comment: It's not clear why you might think ebooks are *not* suitable for this purpose?

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Though the answer to your question is primitive, I'll include it in the answer section nonetheless.

Comment: slightly related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17825/12454

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. There is absolutely no difference in the citing a digital material of the same printed book as a reference. You may cite the e-book just the way you would do with the printed book. This applies not only to your bachelor thesis but to all publishable content. Just make sure you get the edition and the page references, pp, right (if any).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was thinking about using e-book that isn't printed, that is just a digital material and never will be a printed book.

Comment: There are many of such books and even journal articles that do not occur in printed matter. They can also be cited in exactly the same way. On the other hand. if the publisher of the material is unknown, i.e., you cannot find the related publisher even over the internet for the material you wish to refer, you may cite it as a web reference along with the corresponding URL.

Comment: Small addition: Not all e-books actually have pages in the traditional sense - the page numbers change as soon as you change the font size. It makes more sense to use the chapter/section number instead in such a case.

Comment: Agreed. Some articles exclusive to digital print do not have page numbers. I have made the necessary edit to the answer.